# Change column name while unparsing using Papa parser

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, papaparse

I have a array of object which i want to convert it into CSV format using `Papa Parser` javascript library.

so far I am able to convert the array of object using `Papa.unparse` function but the issue with this is column name. Is there a way to provide the custom column name in `Papa.unparse` function so that I do not have to clone my existing array of object into to another array of object with altered column name.

```
    var csvVal = Papa.unparse(callHistoryArray,{
                    quotes: false, //or array of booleans
                    delimiter: ",",
                    header: true,
                    newline: "\r\n",                        
                    columns: [
                            "_name",
                            "_number",                          
                            "_type",
                            "_mode",
                            "_duration",
                            "_objType",
                            "_dateTime"

                    ], //or array of strings


                }
        );
```

it generates following output

```
_name,_number,_type,_mode,_duration,_objType,_dateTime
Willey W,2314651324,outgoing,,0:50,Contact,1573553784000
```

Instead of this I am expecting

```
'Name','Number','Type','Mode','Duration','Entity','DateTime'
Willey W,2314651324,outgoing,,0:50,Contact,1573553784000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose not to create a header when parsing the data, and then create a header an concat them.

**Example:**

```js
var callHistoryArray = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }];

var csvVal = Papa.unparse(callHistoryArray, {
  header: false,
  columns: [
    "a",
    "b",
  ], //or array of strings
});

var headersVal = Papa.unparse({ fields: ['id', 'value'], data: [] });

var result = headersVal + csvVal;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Papaparse wouldn't take column headers and data together, no matter what I tried. So, I ended up using your solution! It is neat.